# Accessing custom settings from managed package global class

Tags: apex, community, customsetting

We have global class in managed package so users can create a visualforce page and refer that global class we exposed. from that visualforce page global class we are trying to access the protected custom settings.

now visualforce page is giving an error you dont have level of access to custom setting.

How to solve this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to provide an example of your code that is creating the issue and the verbatim text of the error.

Comment: Visualforce pages can't _directly_ display protected custom settings, but you should be able to access them in Apex.